# Encontrar div com o valor de atributo igual à selecionada com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho vários botões com `data-numBtn` numérico e com valor igual ao das div (com atributo `data-slide`) que controla. Resumindo, gostava que ao clicar por ex: no `.btn` com `data-numBtn="3"` acontece-se algo (por ex: fadeIn) à `.img` com `data-slide="3"` também. PS: Os elementos vão ser carregados dinamicamente, sem pevisão de quantos vão ser, os elementos `data-numBtn` e `data-slide` vão sempre coincidir.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn" data-numBtn="1">...</div>
<div class="btn" data-numBtn="2">...</div>
<div class="btn" data-numBtn="3">...</div>
<div class="btn" data-numBtn="4">...</div>

<div class="img" data-slide="1">...</div>
<div class="img" data-slide="2">...</div>
<div class="img" data-slide="3">...</div>
<div class="img" data-slide="4">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os seus elementos são carregados dinamicamente vai precisar de delegar esse evento. Assim sugiro usar `$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){` que vai procurar o elemento com a classe `btn` somente quando o click surgir e não quando carrega o código para o caso de ele ainda não estar lá.

Para ler esse atributo `data` pode usar o `.data()` do jQuery. Um código possivel para esse problema seria:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var numBtn = $(this).data('numBtn');
    $('.img[data-slide="' + numBtn + '"]').fadeIn();
});
```

No caso de haver numeros que choquem uns com os outros vai ter de usar o `.index()` para saber qual a posição desse `.btn` relativo aos outros, ignorando o atributo `data`. Se fôr esse o seu caso pode usar assim:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var numBtn = $(this).index();
    $('.img[data-slide]').eq(numBtn);
});
```

Comment: Já que não está fazendo nenhuma outra operação com **numBtn** poderia removê-la e usar diretamente no seletor (primeiro código) ou no jQuery.eq() (segundo)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto verdade. Como sugere ficaria mais pequeno o código. Deixei assim para ser mais claro, passo a passo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode selecionar a imagem utilizando a classe `.img` e o próprio atributo `data-slide`. Para selecionar a imagem 3:

```
$('.img[data-slide="3"]');
```

Para selecionar a imagem correspondente ao botão, basta:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
   var btnId = $(this).attr('data-numBtn'); // pega o id do botão clicado
   var $img = $('.img[data-slide="'+btnId+'"]'); // seleciona a imagem correspondente ao id do botão clicado

   $img.fadeIn(); 
});
```